# Creating a DataFrame from other 2 dataframes based on coditions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 csv file. They have one common column which is *ID*. What I want to do is I want to extract the common rows and built another dataframe. Firstly, I want to select job, and after that, as I said they have one common column, I want to find the rows whose IDs are the same. Visually, the dataframe should be seen like this:

Let first DataFrame is:

| #ID | #Gender | #Job | #Shift | #Wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | Engineer | Night | 8000 |
| 2 | Male | Engineer | Night | 7865 |
| 3 | Female | Worker | Day | 5870 |
| 4 | Male | Accountant | Day | 5870 |
| 5 | Female | Architecture | Day | 4900 |

Let second one is:

| #ID | #Department |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IT |
| 2 | Quality Control |
| 5 | Construction |
| 7 | Construction |
| 8 | Human Resources |

And the new DataFrame should be like:

| #ID | #Department | #Job | #Wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IT | Engineer | 8000 |
| 2 | Quality Control | Engineer | 7865 |
| 5 | Construction | Architecture | 4900 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df_result = df1.merge(df2, on = 'ID', how = 'inner')
```

If you want to select only certain columns from a certain `df` use:

```
df_result = df1[['ID','Job', 'Wage']].merge(df2[['ID', 'Department']], on = `ID`, how = 'inner')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = df2.merge(df1[['ID','Job', 'Wage']], on='ID')
```